# python, how to select element from each column of matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I need to extract one element from each column of a matrix according to an index vector. Say:

```
index = [0,1,1]
matrix = [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Index vector tells me I need the first element from column 1, second element from column 2, and third element from column 3.

The output should be `[1,5,8]`. How can I write it out without explicit loop?

Thanks

Comment: Your example seems pretty non-general. What about an index vector like [0, 2]? What about [0, 0, 1, 2]? Should these also be covered?

Comment: No need for considering this. Dim of index vector is equal to number of columns of matrix

Comment: I change the index vector, which is first one from column 1, the second from column 2 and 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
index = np.array([0,1,2])
matrix = np.array([[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]])

res = matrix[np.arange(matrix.shape[0]), index]
# array([1, 5, 9])
```

For your second example, reverse your indices:

```
index = np.array([0,1,1])
matrix = np.array([[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]])

res = matrix[index, np.arange(matrix.shape[1])]
# array([1, 5, 8])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But I need to select w.r.t columns. This one works for rows.

Comment: @MichaelSun, Can you be clearer? The output is `[1, 5, 9]` as per desired output in your question.

Comment: V0.15 has added a `np.take_along_axis` function that does this kind of indexing.  It's interesting reading.

Comment: @hpaulj, Thanks, I definitely need to upgrade!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working with 2-dimensional matrices, I'd suggest using `numpy`. Then, in your case, you can just use [`np.diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix = np.array([[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]])
>>> matrix
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
>>> np.diag(matrix)
array([1, 5, 9])
```

However, @jpp's solution is more generalizable. My solution is useful in your case because you really just want the diagonal of your matrix.

Comment: I should make question more clear. That one is just one example. I need more general thing like get i,j,k element from three columns respectively

Comment: Then you should go with @jpp's solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
val = [matrix[i][index[i]] for i in range(0, len(index))]
```

Comment: I think OP said *How can I write it out without explicit loop*